# How to set a custom value to a number field with react-admin

Tags: react-admin

I have a record with a `totalPrice` and a `saleCommission` fields.

I use the `NumberField` to properly display the price:

```js
const RideShow: FC<ShowProps> = (props) => (
  <Show
    {...props}
  >
    <SimpleShowLayout>
      <NumberField
        source="totalPrice"
        label="Prix total"
        locales={['fr']}
        options={{
          style: 'currency',
          currency: 'EUR',
        }}
      />
    </SimpleShowLayout>
  </Show>
);
```

Now I would like to show the price minus the sale commission, a data I don't have from the API.

The only way I found is to [create a custom field](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Fields.html#third-party-components),
but I have to copy/paste almost all the logic of the `NumberField`:

```js
const WithoutCommissionPriceField: FC<FieldProps<RideRecord>> = ({ record }) => {
  if (!record) {
    return null;
  }

  const price = record.totalPrice - record.totalPrice * record.saleCommission;

  return (
    <Typography
      variant="body2"
      component="span"
    >
      {price.toLocaleString('fr', {
        style: 'currency',
        currency: 'EUR',
      })}
    </Typography>
  );
};
```

It works, but the only thing I need is the custom price value.

How can I avoid code duplication by using directly `NumberField` with a custom value?

Update: I found a way to re-use the `NumberField`:

```js
const WithoutCommissionPriceField: FC<FieldProps<RideRecord>> = ({ record, ...props }) => {
  if (!record) {
    return null;
  }

  record.totalPriceWithoutCommission = record.totalPrice - record.totalPrice * record.saleCommission;

  return (
    <NumberField
      record={record}
      source="totalPriceWithoutCommission"
      locales={['fr']}
      options={{
        style: 'currency',
        currency: 'EUR',
      }}
      {...props}
    />
  );
};
```

But the way I have to change the record content still looks a bit hacky to me.

Comment: This is the proper way to do it. You are doing just fine I guess.

Comment: @Striped this is indeed the best I found so far, however I don't like the way I update the record itself from a custom field component. Maybe I have instead to transform the value before the render? But I don't know how to do that properly for now.

Comment: Actually you have two easy choices: your way, with an external field getting the record OR using a `FunctionField`. I don't see another way to achieve it easily.

Comment: I don't see how to use the `FunctionField` and keep the `NumberField` feature. Is it possible. For the external field method, do you have a sample? If you make a complete answer, I'll be glad to test it and mark it as validated if it works! :-)